# Making a makefile for C program on linux

Tags: c, makefile

I have a C programming  exercise, which I have written (and runs perfectly) in Visual Studio on Windows. I now have to make sure it runs OK on Linux as well, and need to create a makefile for it (it is part of the assignment). Here is my makefile:

```
all: genericdfs.a sudSolver

genericdfs.a: genericdfs.c genericdfs.h
    gcc -Wvla -c genericdfs.c
    ar rs genericdfs.a genericdfs.c

sudSolver.o: sudSolver.c sudTree.h genericdfs.h
    gcc -Wvla -c sudSolver.c    -lm

sudukutree.o: sudTree.c sudTree.h
    gcc -c sudTree.c -lm

sudSolver: sudSolver.o sudTree.o genericdfs.a
    gcc -Wvla sudSolver.o sudTree.o -L. -lgenericdfs -o sudukusolver -lm

clean:
    rm -f sudSolver.o
    rm -f sudTree.o
    rm -f genericfs.o
```

OK so the main C file is sudSolver which has includes for sudTree.h and math.h (hence the -lm)

sudTree.c includes sudTree.h and genericdfs.h as well.

One of the requirements is to create a .a library which should be linked to the main C file at the linkage operation.

We were given next to nothing of an explanation as how to write these makefiles so all I wrote above was according to makefile tutorials I found online.

This makefile however doesn't work, there seems to be a problem with the linkage to the library as this is the error that is being returned:

> cannot find cannot find -lgenericdfs

I tried shifting things around but nothing seems to work, another error which appeared when I put -L. genericfs.a in the linkage line:

> genericdfs.a: error adding symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one

Could anyone please explain how I link to the .a library which was created? I suppose its not that complicated but for the life of me I cannot get it to work

Thank you to anyone who helps!

**EDIT** 
I managed to make it work by changing the line

```
ar rs genericdfs.a genericdfs.c
```

into

```
ar rs libgenericdfs.a genericdfs.o
```

and updating final linkage line to libgenericdfs.a

But now there is a different problem. I included a couple rm -f commands to a clean: tag, but they don't delete the files written there when i run "make" from the terminal.

If I run "make clean" then everything gets removed. Do I need to add "clean" to the "all" tag at the top? I read that you should not do that

Comment: Shouldn't genericdfs.a be at the gcc command line of sudSolver? Right now, it just appears as a dependency.

Comment: @LordHenryWotton how do you mean? as I said I don't have a lot of experience with makefiles :P

Comment: The name of the library should be libgenericdfs.a

Comment: @PaulR I changed the line -L. -lgenericdfs.a to -L. -libgenericdfs.a and the same error pops up, it doesn't know what it is

Comment: I think you should learn how to do it without makefiles first. It shouldn't take too long, since the program has a small number of modules. [This](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs50/buildlib.html) seems like a good set of instructions.

Comment: Is the genericdfs.a library actually called libgenericdfs.a ? If not, then gcc won't find it unless you supply the full path to the lib.

Comment: @DavidWoo managed to make it work, I Edited my post. But now clean won't run :/

Comment: What's the clean command look like in the makefile?

Comment: @DavidWoo edited the post to include the clean command as well (hadn't noticed it wasn't there)

Comment: And what is not working about it?

Comment: @DavidWoo When i run "make" from the terminal, it creates all files as it should, but does not clean up. If i write "make clean" in the terminal immediately after it cleans the files. Is there a way to clean up the files automatically without calling "make clean" manually?

Comment: Try removing -f from rm command and seeing what output you get. I can't see how everything could possibly be getting removed. Another thing to try is replace rm command with echo commands to see what happens when you call clean. You don't need to add clean to all.

Answer (score 1):

gcc is passed libraries by using

```
gcc -Lfull/path/to/library
```

Or if the library name starts with 'lib' and is on a library search path then you can use -l with lib and .a removed. For example with library called libtest.a .

```
gcc -ltest
```

There are a couple of special cases for well used libraries like maths -lm and zlib I think.